# bootstrap date picker missing link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hello Below is the code for bootstrap date picker, may i know why it is not work. What is the link I miss out.

I'm using the latest version for bootstrap which is version 3.3.6.

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrintStudio.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css?parameter=1" />
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label for="InputMessage">Expected Delivery Date</label>


                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>


       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                pickTime: false
            });
        });
</script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why calling $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker  twice ? ?

Comment: it will not work if i call once

Comment: Wrong Michael, [**it will**](https://jsfiddle.net/eb3ytoh1/).. make sure you've loaded neccessary scripts and stylesheets and see what potential errors your console give you.

Comment: i'm no idea why it not work. i'm referring alot example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server">
          <title></title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css?parameter=1" />
          <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       </head>
       <body>
          <form id="form1" runat="server">
             <div>
                <label for="InputMessage">Expected Delivery Date</label>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                   <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                   <span class="input-group-addon">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                   </span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                 });
             });
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

And then use the options from date picker that you like.

Comment: what is the diff between you code and mine ? may i know why? this problem i'm stuck for one morning

Comment: @Michael you have placed your script tags inside the form tag. This'll not load the scripts.

Comment: Thx ! no wonder I'm wired. Why sometime Js must insert at master page. For this situation, if i'm using master page, for ContentPlaceHolder section I'm not able to insert Js? i should create a js file ?

Comment: That will make your markup look haphazard. 
Try putting your scripts in ContentPlaceHolder's head. 
Creating a new Js would also be fine.